Is it true that $[k(x,y):k(f,g)] \leq \deg_{1,1}(f) \deg_{1,1}(g)$? $f,g \in k[x,y]$
Let $f,g \in k[x,y]$, $k$ is a field of characteristic zero.
Denote $d_1=\deg_{1,0}(f)=\deg_x(f)$,
$d_2=\deg_{0,1}(f)=\deg_y(f)$,$d=\deg_{1,1}(f)$
and
$e_1=\deg_{1,0}(f)=\deg_x(g)$,
$e_2=\deg_{0,1}(f)=\deg_y(g)$,
$e=\deg_{1,1}(g)$.
It is known that $[k(x,y):k(x,f)]=d_2$,
$[k(x,y):k(y,f)]=d_1$, $[k(x,y):k(x,g)]=e_2$,
$[k(x,y):k(y,f)]=e_1$; see the first comment to this post.
Also, in the thesis of Y. Zhang, he proved that a Jacobian pair $Jac(f,g)=f_xg_y-f_yg_x \in k^*$ (here I am not assuming that $f,g$ is a Jacobian pair!) satisfy:
$[k(x,y):k(f,g)] \leq \min \{\deg_y(f),\deg_y(g)\}$;
this result does not hold in general, for example,
$[k(x,y):k(x,y^{10})]=10 > \min \{0,10\}$, even if we take total degrees:
$[k(x,y):k(x,y^{10})]=10 > \min \{1,10\}$.
Question:
Is $[k(x,y):k(f,g)] \leq \deg_{1,1}(f) \deg_{1,1}(g)$ true?
I think that the claim is true, and there is a result concerning zeros of polynomials
which may be relevant here, but I am not sure.
An attempt to find a solution:
$k(x,f) \subseteq k(x,f,g) \subseteq k(x,y)$,
hence $[k(x,y): k(x,f,g)]| d_2$,
and similarly,
$k(x,g) \subseteq k(x,f,g) \subseteq k(x,y)$,
hence $[k(x,y): k(x,f,g)] | e_2$.
(Similarly, $[k(x,y): k(y,f,g)] | d_1, e_1$.)
Then $k(f,g) \subseteq k(x,f,g) \subseteq k(x,y)$ implies that
$[k(x,y):k(f,g)]$ is a multiple of $[k(x,y):k(x,f,g)]$.
If, for example $\gcd(d_2,e_2)=1$, then $[k(x,y): k(x,f,g)]=1$,
so there is no information on $[k(x,y):k(f,g)]$:
" $[k(x,y):k(f,g)]$ is a multiple of $1$ ".
Also, $k(f,g) \subseteq k(x,f,g) \subseteq k(x,y)$ implies that
$[k(x,y):k(f,g)]$ is a multiple of $[k(x,f,g):k(f,g)] \leq \deg m(x, k(f,g))$, the degree of the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $k(f,g)$.
Any comments are welcome! Thank you.

A non-counterexample: $f=xy^2,g=xy^4$. $[k(x,y):k(f,g)=[k(x,y):k(x,y^2)=2$
